# PCH compiler options for MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, precompiled-headers

I am a bit confused about when to use `/Yc` (*create* PCH) as opposed to `/Yu` (*use* PCH.) For a project that has never used precompiled headers in the past, naturally, the PCH file will not exist initially. Am I supposed to fire off a initial build with `/Yc`, have it create the PCH file and then change the setting to `/Yu` for all subsequent builds?

That can't possibly be it, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: Create a header to contain all the headers to pre-compile eg: `stdafx.h` (this MUST be the 1st include in all `.cpp` files).  File to generate the PCH: `stdafx.cpp` which only includes `stdafx.h` and compile this with `/Yc`.  All other .cpp files include `stdafx.h` at the start and compile with `/Yu`.  MSVC is clever enough to do the `/Yc` file 1st.

Comment: Richard: Of course, those are the standard steps to take when enabling PCH builds and I have done that. My question is what _else_ should I do?

Comment: Don't understand - the standard steps obviously do work - so you need to explain why they don't work for you.

Comment: The project I am dealing with keeps complaining that it cannot open the PCH file (no such file or directory.) That was the reason why I asked if I should do a /Yc build first before changing it to /Yu.

Comment: Sorry. I re-read your reply and indeed, in this case, I added the stdafx.cpp file myself (instead of it being auto-generated when you create a project.) I had forgotten to set /Yc at the file level on stdafx.cpp. Thank you!